# Determining when UITextView begins new row

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview, row

Is there anyway to determine when a a UITextview begins a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure the text in it and compare to the width of the UITextView

```
[textView.text textView.font textView.bounds.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].width
```